# webページのソースに貼られたリンク先のhtmlファイルを取得する

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

やりたいことは[リンクHP](http://163.49.30.82/cgi-bin/DspDamData.exe?KIND=1&ID=1368030375180&BGNDATE=20180705&ENDDATE=20180711&KAWABOU=NO)（下のpythonコードのurlと同じです）の背景がグレーの部分のデータをDataframeに格納することです．
背景がグレーの部分はリンク先のページに埋め込まれたhtmlファイルとなっていまして，リンクHPのソースを見ると

```
html
</TABLE>
  <IFRAME src="/html/frm/DamFreeData2018071116325029223.html" 
  scrolling="AUTO" width="840" height="65%" align="center" frameborder="0"  
  style="border-width : 0px 0px 0px 0px;"></IFRAME>
</CENTER>
```

の「/html/frm/DamFreeData2018071116325029223.html」にデータのリンクが張られています．直接pandas.read_html(/html/frm/DamFreeData2018071116325029223.html)するのも1つの解決策なのですが，事情により最初に冒頭のHPに接続して，ソースのhtmlから'/html/frm/DamFreeData2018071116325029223.html'を取得したいのです．

現状は

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url='http://163.49.30.82/cgi-bin/DspDamData.exeKIND=1&ID=609061289920060&BGNDATE=20120701&ENDDATE=20120731&KAWABOU=NO'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
#dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0,index_col=0)#htmlを読み込む
print(dfs)
```

とするとほしいデータの部分がNaNと表示されてしまいます．どなたか解決策を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の段階にわけて処理する必要があると思います。

1. 任意期間ダム諸量検索結果 ページへのアクセス
2. iframeのsrc取得
3. iframeのsrcからデータ読み込み

`python scraping`をキーワードに見付けた、以下の記事を参考に記載しています。

[PythonでWebスクレイピングする時の知見をまとめておく](https://vaaaaaanquish.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/06/25/202924)

### 事前インストール

```
$ pip install requests beautifulsoup4 lxml
```

### コード

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse

# 任意期間ダム諸量検索結果 ページへのアクセス
page_url = "http://163.49.30.82/cgi-bin/DspDamData.exe?KIND=1&ID=1368030375180&BGNDATE=20180705&ENDDATE=20180711&KAWABOU=NO"    
res = requests.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

#  iframeのsrc取得
data_src = soup.iframe['src']  #=> /html/frm/DamFreeData2018071300300727273.html
data_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(page_url, data_src) #=> http://163.49.30.82/html/frm/DamFreeData2018071300194826006.html

#  iframeのsrcからデータ読み込み
dfs = pd.read_html(data_url)
print(dfs)
```

Comment: 読みやすいコードを見せていただき感謝です．おかげさまでbeautiful soupの挙動が理解できました．ありがとうございました